# what is ng-hide-add, ng-hide-active

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm animating a div. It has the following definition:

```
<div ng-show="showTranslations" ng-swipe-right="showTranslationsBlock=false">...</div>
```

I have the following css defined:

```
div.ng-hide {
    transition: 0.5s linear opacity;
    opacity: 0;
}

div.ng-hide-add, 
div.ng-hide-remove {
    /* this needs to be here to make it visible during the animation
       since the .ng-hide class is already on the element rendering
       it as hidden. */
    display:block!important;
}
```

This is taken from [this tutorial](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html). The animation works. But:

1. Why do I need these classes `.ng-hide-add` and `.ng-hide-remove`?
2. Why I don't see them added to div's classes?
3. Why there are also classes `ng-hide-add-active` and `ng-hide-remove-active`?
4. Why there is no transition when the div becomes visible although I've added the following css rule:

   `div.ng-hide-remove {
       opacity: 1;
   }`

**UPDATE**

1. As I can see from the table provided by google's tutorial these classes are added to trigger `animation frame (this performs a reflow)`. Is my understanding correct? Why is `animation frame` is mentioned there?
2. I tried to increase the transition period but it didn't add the classes. I didn't see the classes `ng-hide-add-active` and `ng-hide-remove-active` added either.
3. As I understand from the table these are the classes that trigger transition?

**UPDATE1**
I've explored the Angular's source code and found the following for the `ng-hide` directive:

```
var ngHideDirective = ['$animate', function($animate) {
  return function(scope, element, attr) {
    scope.$watch(attr.ngHide, function ngHideWatchAction(value){
      $animate[toBoolean(value) ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass'](element, 'ng-hide');
    });
  };
}];
```

As I understand the `ng-hide` class is added through animation service. But what happens if I don't use animations and `$animate` service is not available? How Angular is going to handle this situation given the code above and how it is going to add `ng-hide` class? Or is this `$animate.addClass()` simply adds a callback to `addClass` event?

[image]

Comment: could you please provide any fiddle?

Comment: 1. They are intended to be used with CSS transitions. 2. Just increase your transition period, you will see them: transition: 10s linear opacity; 3. I don't believe the tutorial is showing how the css classes were intended to be used with animations. 4. Apply the CSS animations as intended: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide

Comment: did you include ngAnimate as a dependency: app.module('app', ['ngAnimate']); Angular will not add the CSS classes otherwise.

Comment: @pixelbits, yes, I included it as a dependency and there are no errors in console.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Put your CSS transition on ng-hide-remove, ng-hide-remove-active:

```
div.ng-hide-remove {
    transition: 0.5s linear opacity;
    opacity: 0;
}


div.ng-hide-remove-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Similarly, for ng-hide-add and ng-hide-add-active:

```
div.ng-hide-add {
    transition: 0.5s linear opacity;
    opacity: 1;
}


div.ng-hide-add-active {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! You're by far the most helpful person for me during my study of Angular :). Appreciate!

Comment: And now a few more clarifications: 1. Is my understanding correct that I should always put `transition` property on the class that precedes `-active` class? So that basicallt the animation happens between adding the `myclass-add` and `myclass-add-active` classes?

Comment: Could you also please add comments regarding my `update1` in my original question?